# Python: Reference of lists

Tags: python

I tried to put this line in my code, attempting to create a 80*80 grid:

```
a = [[0] * 80] * 80
```

However, it turned out that I have 80 reference to the same lists, and it took me really long to realize this problem.

I am wondering is there a way to understand/memorize how python reference in common methods?

Thanks!

Comment: It is in [Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list)

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you do this you'll have N references of the same list.

If you want to have different lists that you can manipulate independently, you can do the following:

```
a = [[0 for x in xrange(80)] for y in xrange(80)]
```

Note that I'm using xrange and not range: this is a generator and will not allocate the range in memory.

Comment: Is there any other scenario where I might unknowingly run into list reference?

Comment: It's the main one where I've seen people make errors, you usually don't have to worry too much about references in Python in contrast to other languages.

Comment: Yup .. Why dont you use numpy for these? It is extremely useful for matrices manipulation..

Comment: Yes if you use a list as a default parameter in a function, it is always the same list object. `def t(k=[]): k.append(1)` modifies always the same list if you use the default parameter.

Comment: You don't need the inner `xrange`, just the outer one, because the objects in the inner list are immutable.

Comment: Yes you need to determine whether the object you are copying is mutable or immutable and that should determine when you might run into this scenario again.